# soldering new connector to pc mainboard

Tags: pcie, pc

I know this is probably not the right forum but anyway. I have this old mainboard **01AJ155**.

In the picture below you can see it has two PCI x16 connections. One connector is used by my graphis card. I want to solder another PCI x16 connector.
I tried to lookup the datasheet but I could only find this user manual from lenovo: **ideacentre Y700–900 Hardware Maintenance Manual**. Link: https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1037506121.pdf
On p.30 you can see it also states two PCI x16 ports. My question is will this new connector work or is it without function (not connected to anyhting)?

[image]

Comment: Site rules: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - in other words, this is purchasable product and you should consult the manufacturer or its data sheet to get the right answer. If information is not available, it doesn't naturally become a valid question on this site (not a forum BTW).

Comment: Chanses are soldering a connector won't give you a new PCIE connector which you can use.

Comment: OK thank you. I will have to contact lenovo. Its weird that they don't have a datasheet for this

Comment: Modification questions are allowed.

Comment: But essentially the answer is we don't know. It may work it may not. Plenty of mods online where someone soldered on a header and it worked. Sometimes it may need extras like a jumper connection and others may need multiple passive components added. But the biggest question is if its active in the OS. Does windows or Linux report there is a second pci slot available? If not then adding a header isn't going to do much.

Comment: @Passerby I will look it up on windows. I don't have the mainboard currently here. If it itsn't reported there. There is no chance it will work?

Comment: Without flashing the board/chips/bios somehow no. Its highly unlikely.